# I want to hide the image when clicked. Calling function when element.onclick not working

Tags: javascript

```
var image = document.getElementById("image");

function hide(el){
  el.hidden = true;
}

image.onclick = hide(image);
```

I've gone over this part countless times, but I'm not smart enough to see why it isn't working. Thanks for the help lads.

THE HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chore Door!</title>
    <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="image"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/closed_door.svg" id="image></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML tag for the image? Does it have an id of "image" Any errors?

Comment: @BasSlagter Sure, one sec

Answer (score 3):

Your function is called and executed on page load. Call the function inside of an anonymous function.

**Please Note:** You do not have any element with `id=image`.

```js
var image = document.getElementById("image");

function hide(el){
  el.hidden = true;
}

image.onclick = function(){ hide(image) };
```

```html
<div id="image"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/closed_door.svg" id="image"></div>
```

Probably the following demo will help you to clear your doubts:

```js
var image = document.getElementById("image");
function hide(){
  image.hidden = true;
}

image.onclick = hide; // notice there is no () after the function name, here the function will not be executed on page load
```

```html
<div id="image"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/chore-door/images/closed_door.svg" id="image"></div>
```

Comment: Why is my function called on page load when it isn't an IIFE? And when the image hasn't been clicked yet? wtf

Comment: @lukact, when calling a function, `()` after the function invokes the function immediately...

Comment: I wonder why this works since there are no images with an id of "image"

Comment: @BasSlagter, in my answer, of course img has an *id*:)

Comment: I get that...but not in the OP ;)

Comment: Don't get caught up in the lack of the "image"-id since it wouldn't have worked even if it was there.

Comment: @lukact, that is just another issue. You did post HTML and JavaScript code, you should have connection between them:)

Comment: I just dont get why the function is called immidiately and not when image.onclick.

Comment: @Mamun, that's not the problem either

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("image").addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.hidden = true;
}
```

Comment: Would you recommend EventListeners over onclick. Why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick

Answer (score 0):

As i look at your HTML, there is no image with the id of "image" So no element will be returned on the `document.getElementById("image")` call.

You might want to use `getElementsByTagName("image")` instead but note that this is an array of elements.